# Javascript Race condition for Promises

Tags: javascript, promise, race-condition

Let's say I have three async functions:

`functionPromise1, functionPromise2, functionPromise3`

I want all three to be called concurrently, with the following details:

- If `functionPromise1` is rejected, stop the other two functions from
  finishing.
- If `functionPromise2` and `functionPromise3` both finish and are resolved, continue to the next part of the code, but if `functionPromise1` is eventually rejected then don't go on further into the code.
- If `functionPromise2` or `functionPromise3` are rejected, don't go on to the next part of the code.

My use case for these functions is that `functionPromise1` serves as an input validation that I want to make synchronous with other functions that treat input as already validated in order to speed up my process. However, if the input is at any point found to be invalid by `functionPromise1`, I want to terminate the code.

```
function functionPromise2(...){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        fetchUrl(url, function(err, meta, body){
            if (err) { reject(err); } else {
                if (body.toString().indexOf(text) !== -1){
                    resolve();
                } else {
                    reject("Could not find quote");
                }
            }
        });
    });
}

function functionPromise3(...) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        var id = shortid.generate();
        var fileName = id+'.png';
        webshot(url, fileName, { shotOffset: {left: mouseX, top: mouseY} }, function(err) {
            if (err) { reject(err); } else {
                resolve({id: id, fileName: fileName});   
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: When you say 'synchronous' do you perhaps mean 'concurrent'?  because otherwise the question makes little sense.

Comment: @john_omalley I do mean concurrent. I was assuming they were synonymous. I'll change it now

Comment: @mhodges Wouldn't that mean they would be run asynchronously?

Comment: Short answer is you can't. If you want 2 and 3 being called to be dependent on 1 resolving, you can't call them till 1 is done. JavaScript has run-to-completion function semantics, you can't cancel a function call while its running, whether its in a promise or not. You can easily do the rest of it.

Comment: Promises cannot be "stopped", if you are doing any processing that can be stopped you'll need to do it manually. Please show us what your `functionPromise2` and `functionPromise3` are doing.

Comment: @Bergi I've added the code.

Comment: Keep in mind that JS is (unless you use web workers) single-threaded. There is no 'parallel' execution..

Comment: @db2791 How can you terminate `fetchUrl`? How can you terminate `webshot()`? It doesn't look like they can be stopped after being started.

Comment: @db2791 I misunderstood the question, then, when you used the word `synchronously` rather than `concurrently`. With your updated question, though, the others are right. It depends what your 2 and 3 functions are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the "continue to the next part of the code", you're essentially looking for `Promise.all` which waits for everything and immediately rejects if there's an error in any promise:

```
return Promise.all([functionPromise1(), functionPromise2(), functionPromise3()]);
```

To stop the latter two processes when `functionPromise1()` rejects, there is nothing that promises can handle for you, you'll need to do that manually.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question really depends upon what functionPromise2 and functionPromise3 do.  If both simply perform, say, one I/O operation, then you just want to use `Promise.all([f1, f2, f3])`.  If they are more involved (i.e. multiple callbacks) then you would need to keep state somewhere to hold the result from the first promise and check it during the intermediate steps of the second and third promises.

You can't really have true race conditions in single-threaded Javascript.  In the interest of simplicity I would make sure the straightforward solution - the `Promise.all` or `f1.then(() => Promise.all([f2, f3])` - was not good enough before making it more complex.